# Evaluating the derivative of a Cantor-Vitali function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\varphi \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ a "Cantor-Vitali function", viz. take $x \in [0,1)$ and write it as
$$
x = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_j}{3^j}, \quad a_j \in \{0,1,2\}
$$
with $a_j$ non definitely equal to 2. Then 
$$
\varphi (x) := \begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{a_j}{2^{j+1}} & a_k=1 \text{ and } a_j \ne 1 \quad \forall j \in \{1,2, \ldots , k-1\} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_j}{2^{j+1}} & a_j \ne 1\quad \forall j \in \mathbb N 
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover, put $\varphi(1):=1$.

> **Question**. *Evaluate* $\varphi^{\prime}(x)$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

Well, I think it is not difficult to prove the existence (at least a.e.) of $\varphi^{\prime}$, since the function should be monotone (increasing?), hence differentiable a.e. by Lebesgue's theorem.

The problem is that I cannot understand how to calculate $\varphi^{\prime}(x)$. Is it zero a.e.? How to prove this? How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your assertion of monotonicity implying derivative exists a.e. is true. Indeed the answer is 0. You can find the proof of this in any graduate level real analysis textbook such as Royden or Kolomogorov. The wishy-washy answer is to assert that $f$ has a unique continuous extension, and it's constant on middle-thirds sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\phi$ is constant on each of the open intervals making up the complement of the Cantor set.